# Question on complex limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

With the given function:

$f(z)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+2i$, one does not know if there exists a limit at  $z=0$.

Re-written to:

$f(z)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+2i=\frac{x^2(1+2i)+2iy^2}{x^2+y^2}$, we take the limit :

then we take the limit of x and y separately, with x=-iy:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\longrightarrow0}\frac{x^2(1+2i)+2iy^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2(1+2i)+2iy^2}{2y^2}=\frac{1+4i}{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\longrightarrow0}\frac{x^2(1+2i)+2iy^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2(1+2i)+2iy^2}{2y^2}=\frac{1+4i}{2}
\end{equation}

So the same limit exists for both the two variables as they approach zero, but still, z should not have a limit. Why?

Comment: First of all your calculations are wrong. Check your algebra. Secondly, the limits in different directions have to be equal for the function to have a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By setting $x=-iy$, you compute the same limit twice (taking the limit on $x$ or on $y$ makes no difference);
2. $(-iy)^2\ne y^2$;
3. Even without these mistakes, showing two directions that give the same limit is not enough.
4. Evaluate the limits along $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$.

Comment: Thanks, this  confirmed  Kavi Rama Murthy point, the limits are respectively as x goes towards 0, 2i, and as y goes towards 0, 1+2i. So the function does not exist at z=0.